# How to fread two time same integer which is store in a file?

Tags: c, file

How to `fread()` two times same integer which is stored in a file?  My code is below; please help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int num=12345,i;
    int dupnum[2];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("haha","w");
    fwrite(&num,sizeof(int),1,fp);//here i m writing num in file
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("haha","r");
    fread(&dupnum,sizeof(int),2,fp);// reading from file and store in dupnum 2 times
    fclose(fp);
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    printf("%d\n",dupnum[i]);// here i m printing 2 times but getting garbage and can i avoid array here?
}
```

Comment: You write one number, and try to read two. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write one integer to the file.  You attempt to read two integers from the file that contains but one.  This will fail.  Because you are not checking any of the functions, you don't know this.

As a result, the values in `dupnum` are indeterminate.  There's a moderate chance that `dupnum[0]` contains the written value, but the value in `dupnum[1]` is indeterminate.

You need to do error checking, and you cannot read two values from a file that contains just one value with a single `fread()`.  One way around that is shown below.  Another way would be to write two values to the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void err_exit(const char *msg);

int main(void)
{
    int num = 12345;
    int dupnum[2];
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("haha", "w")) == NULL)
        err_exit("Failed to open file for writing");
    if (fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 1)
        err_exit("Failed to write to file");
    fclose(fp);
    if ((fp = fopen("haha", "r")) == NULL)
        err_exit("Failed to open file for reading");
    if (fread(&dupnum[0], sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 1)
        err_exit("Failed to read one integer from file");
    rewind(fp);
    if (fread(&dupnum[1], sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 1)
        err_exit("Failed to read one integer from file");
    fclose(fp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        printf("%d\n", dupnum[i]);
    return 0;
}

void err_exit(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Strictly, I should check the return value from `fclose()` too (but `rewind()` does not return any value so it can't be checked).

Note that it would be (far) quicker to read the one value and then use: `dupnum[1] = dupnum[0];` to get the value replicated.  (Of course, in a more general program, the contents of the file would not be known in the code that reads the file.  Here you could simply assign `num` to the elements of `dupnum`, but that would be cheating.)

Comment: thanks a lot but your code is producing small error   error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
fnum.c:24:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

Comment: So do as the compiler tells you to do; or you could use `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11`.  Basically, stop using the quarter-century old standard, C89, and use one of the more recent versions instead.  Or remove the `int` from the `for` loop and declare `int i;` near the top of the function.  But since you've got GCC, use C11 unless there's a strong imperative to use some earlier standard.

Comment: ok sir but if (fread(&dupnum, sizeof(int), 1, fp) != 1)  3rd argument is no of times to copy from file if i changing to 2 from 1 then it should copy same integer 2 times but its not happening why please explain i m unable to figure out ?

Comment: The code compiles clean for me using `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror fr.c -o fr` with GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.4 (but it should compile cleanly anywhere).  It runs and works too.

Comment: If you use 2 (or more) for the third argument to `fread()`, there have to be at least that many integers in the file to be read — and in your file, there aren't that many integers to read because you only wrote one.  By changing the count to 1, I read the sole integer in the file twice; the rewind (or an equivalent `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET)`) is needed to ensure the second `fread()` still has something to read.  So, the third argument to `fread()` is the number of units of data (of the size specified by the second argument) that should be read from the file.

Comment: fwrite(&num,sizeof(int),2,fp);// sir i have written 2 times  now i am reading 2 times  if(fread(&dupnum,sizeof(int),2,fp)!=2) but i am not getting value for dumnum[1]?

Comment: for(j=0;j<2;j++) // why its not possible in loop? plz help i have exam tmmr
{
        if(fread((&dupnum[i]),sizeof(int),1,fp)!=1)
        {
                printf("fail to read first one interger from file\n");
                return;
        }
        rewind(fp);
}
sir please help i do have my exam please

Comment: With `fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 2, fp)` you have written `num` and an indeterminate other value to disk; you have not written `num` twice.  The size and number arguments collectively define a number of bytes to be written starting at the byte address that's the first argument.  You'd need an initialized array with two values to write.

Comment: You can read in a loop as shown.  If you've written two values, you can read two values (without the `rewind()` operation).  The `rewind()` was mostly a red herring; it works, but it isn't what you really want to do.  You need to write two values and then read two values (a single write, a single read).  To do so, initialize `dupnum`; print it; write it; zero it; print it again; read into it; print it a third time.